# JavaFX: Organize controls in rows (in gridpane) using FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml, gridpane

I have a GUI with a lot controls (Labels, Textfields, Comboboxes and Checkboxes). I organize them in a Gridpane and would like to have them in rows and columns (like it is intended with gridpane layout).

If I use FXML I write it like this:

```
<GridPane>
   <Label GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="field1"/>
   <TextField GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
   <Label GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="field2"/>
   <TextField GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
</GridPane>
```

Now the issue: If I would like to add a row between row 0 and 1, I need to increase the row index of the following row. Now lets take 20 rows and 5 columns, where I would like to add a row after the first one. This would create a big afford for me to increase the rownumber for every row below the first one.

Is there something like a row-element which positions its child controls in the same row with increasing column numbers? I think of something like this:

```
<GridPane>
   <GridPane.Row>
       <Label text="field1"/>
       <TextField/>
   </GridPane.Row>
   <GridPane.Row>
       <Label text="field2"/>
       <TextField/>
   </GridPane.Row>
</GridPane>
```

I do know of the VBox and HBox, which is pretty much what I want, but I want to have the elements in columns with fixed width.

Comment: although I have no answer to your question, have you considered using `SceneBuilder`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Indeed I already tried it but found it to be too slow with a lot of elements. Additionally the handling is sometimes very difficult. But it might help to do the renumbering of the rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an object to track `rowIndex`.

Java:

```
public class RowCounter {
    private int currentRowIndex = 0;

    /**
     * Return current rowIndex.
     * @return
     */
    public int getCr() {
        return currentRowIndex;
    }

    /**
     * Return current rowIndex and increase it.
     * @return
     */
    public int getNr() {
        return currentRowIndex++;
    }
}
```

FXML:

```xml
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <fx:define>
        <RowCounter fx:id="rc" />
    </fx:define>

    <children>
        <Label text="Name:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="$rc.cr" />
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="$rc.nr" />

        <Label text="Age:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="$rc.cr" />
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="$rc.nr" />

        <Label text="Address:" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="$rc.cr" />
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="$rc.nr" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: unfortunately I stopped any JavaFX development. After lots of readings in the internet I found no suitable solution, but this here could work. I will accept your answer as it sounds the most promising. Thank you and I will consider it if I ever develop in JavaFX again :)

Comment: It works but don't forget to add the import of RowCounter :)